# Can anyone recognise this Batman villain?

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman, character-identification

Can anyone tell me who this villain is and what storyline this scene comes from?

Maybe a strange incarnation of [Solomon Grundy](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/batman/images/6/6f/Solomon_Grundy_003.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111203043352)?

That's definitely [The Ventriloquist and Scarface](https://thehealingtouch.files.wordpress.com/2008/07/dummy2.jpg) in the background anyway.

I found these panels [here](http://kotaku.com/the-27-best-batman-artists-1682381060).

They were illustrated by [Norm Breyfogle](http://normbreyfogle.com/), if that helps.

[image]

Major Stacking's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/80443/20393) is great, it really does look like the new Scarecrow. The only thing stopping me from accepting it are the facts that:

**A**. Since when has Scarecrow been able to pimp slap Batman around?

**B**. Scarecrow is human. The guy in the panel above is full of bullet holes and has a batarang sticking out of his eye. I don't think a normal human could survive those injuries.

Comment: It is not the Scarecrow. It doesn't match his signature look or lack of fighting style. It's not Solomon Grundy. Batman would recognize him and Grundy has never worn a tie or hat. It's not the Rag Doll. He has never had the ability to mix it up with the Batman like this. My only recourse is to try and find the actual comic these panels are pulled from. Maybe tomorrow after work it will come to me. I know I have read this book and it looks like something out of the mid 80's or early 90's.

Comment: @Thaddeus I updated my question with information about the panels themselves, if it helps at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

He's a one-off character called Big Mel, apparently zombified from what looks like biohazardous materials.

He appeared in the one-shot comic book [DC Retroactive: Batman – The '90s](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/DC_Retroactive:_Batman_%E2%80%93_The_%2790s_Vol_1_1), printed in 2011, in the story *"One Night In the Rest of My Life!"*.

[image]

Couple more preview pages at [Comixology](https://www.comixology.com/DC-Retroactive-Batman-the-90s-1/digital-comic/12834).

Comment: Ah! Cool! Cheers Trish.

Comment: Interesting... a resurrected corpse. So, essentially, he's Solomon Grundy 2.0, resurrected via chemical means versus magical.

Answer (score 10):

It's a dude named Big Mel, from [DC Retroactive: Batman The '90s](http://www.comics.org/issue/869528/). He gets zombified by toxic waste or somesuch. Sorry, don't have a picture at the moment; can add one later.